# Meaning of "Skull" as Insult

Tags: meaning, pejorative-language

I am reading *The Last of the Mohicans*.
A group gets lost on their way to Fort Edward.
Then they meet Hawkeye the scout, who accuses their guide of misleading them.
Hawkeye believes the guide's heritage confirms this 
[when he says](http://books.google.com/books?id=-Hw6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=%22nor+do+I+care+by+whom+they+are+adopted%22&source=bl&ots=Hj0Rw7jvpf&sig=heSnZElriuCwHNo9Ps-VlHE81nM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4ScnU9HGOYisyAHByYGYCA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22nor%20do%20I%20care%20by%20whom%20they%20are%20adopted%22&f=false):

> "A Huron!" repeated the sturdy scout, once more shaking his head in open
>   distrust; "they are a thievish race, nor do I care by whom they are adopted;
>   you can never make anything of them but **skulks** and vagabonds. Since you
>   trusted yourself to the care of one of that nation, I only wonder that you
>   have not fallen in with more."

I cannot find a definition of *skull* to match this usage.
A definition I've found in dictionaries that is closer to Hawkeye's intent than
the common meaning of "bone of the head" is this one from
[MacMillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/skull):

> INFORMAL a person's head, or their mind

Especially if used in this derogatory sense cited from 
[CED](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/skull):

> *derogatory often* the head regarded as the mind or intelligence:
>     *to have a dense skull*

Hawkeye is not shy with his criticisms of this tribe.
In the above passage alone he accuses them of thievery, aimlessness, and treachery.
It is possible that by using *skulls* he is insulting their intelligence too.
But this argument seems weak to me, because the traps and ambushes Hawkeye fears the guide leading the group into require some sophistication to execute.

A supposition I think has more merit is that this *skull* is related to *skulduggery*,
which [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/skulduggery) defines as

> underhanded or unscrupulous behavior; *also*: a devious device or trick

The [*skul*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=skulduggery) in *skulduggery*
("apparently an alteration of Scottish *sculdudrie* 'adultery' (1713),
*sculduddery* 'bawdry, obscenity' (1821), a euphemism of uncertain origin")
appears to have a different etymology than the bone-related
[*skull*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=skull) 
("probably from Old Norse *skalli* 'a bald head, skull,'...").
But I cannot find any sources to confirm the connection of Hawkeye's use of *skulls* to this *skul*.

What does Hawkeye mean by calling the tribe "skulls"?

**Edit**: As Leon Conrad points out below, I misquoted the Google book I cited. The correct word is *skulks*. (I have changed it above.) I have e-mailed the source I read from about the typo.

Comment: I wonder if this is an over-read. Maybe he literally means they should be killed for their skulls.  Or people who skull people (in the same manner as braiding people).

Comment: That should have said braining. Stupid autocorrect.

Comment: I agree with @DavidM. I believe he's saying the only thing to do with a Huron is to run them out of their homes (make them homeless, vagabonds) or killing them (hit them over the head with a club.)

Comment: @DavidM Braiding people would be dreadful. It sounds to me like he is saying that they are either dead (skulls) or no-goods. A lot like General Sheridan's opinion that "the only good Indian is a dead Indian".

Comment: @DavidM and JSanchez: Possibly. I've also seen *to crown*, meaning to hit someone on the crown. But why did Hawkeye turn it into a noun? By analogy, how common was/is it to call people who *brain*, *brains*? Or who *crown*, *crowns*? I am still getting used to the characters, but Hawkeye is described as a "genuine white" (p 30) who boasts that he will speak "in English that the king needn't be ashamed to answer" (p 37) before engaging the group. This boast may be empty since he shuns book-smarts (p 30). And he has used imagery ("hound" p 39). But nothing the group doesn't seem to understand.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is is the result of a typo or mis-reading of the original text, which was cited in the OPs question.

Comment: That's apparently a fairly common typo, because it came up in 7 pages of e-texts on a verbatim Google search.  There was likely an original e-text that got passed around, and around.

Comment: @DavidM The typo still invalidates the question, unless he wants to correct it in the title - which doesn't seem to be the case as the accepted answer is just pointing it out.

Comment: Popularized in the TV show *Third Watch*, a Skull is a career criminal; street trash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original is '[skulks](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/skulk?s=t)', not 'skulls'.

The meaning intended here is a person who shirks their duty.

Comment: Good find. And it was right in the OP's original citation.

Comment: Excellent catch! My apologies. I was reading from [another source](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/940/940-h/940-h.htm) and did not notice the difference in the two texts. This makes a lot more sense, because Hawkeye does refer to some who hide in the forest as "skulkers" (p 35). Thanks!

Comment: @dingo_dan Do not feel bad!  Take a look at my answer below!

Answer (score 2):

I'm 100% certain that skulks the proper original.  But, I wanted to show everyone just how common this typo is!

Click to enlarge:

6 Pages of results (verbatim search)

[image]

vs

7 Pages of results (verbatim search)

[image]

It seems that this is one of those ebooks that has been public domain for a long time, and the same typography error has blazed a trail all the way across the internet!

It just goes to show you... When in doubt, google the words that make sense in context, too.

Comment: a better crop job could be nice

Comment: @user1306322 There you go.  Better cropped.

Comment: Not only that, but the _incorrect_ "skulls and vagabonds" is recommended when we search the _correct_ "skulks and vagabonds," but not the other way around! (Probably because between the two phrases, it's the more confusing and thus the more Google-searched.) This typo shall not plague the literary world any longer! :)

Comment: @dingo_dan That may be because I had searched it right before the correct version.  I'm not sure how El Goog works those suggestions.

Comment: Hm, I did that too. In any case, I will be sure to check if a curious phrase is a typo before I research it any further. And putting images of the text from Google books into my posts when possible would help prevent transcription errors. Thanks, guys! Trying to reason out "Why skulls?" on my own would have driven me crazy.